# Why is email displaying mime boundary in body/

Tags: php, mime

I am trying to send an email via PHP mail() with attachments.

The attachments come through OK and the content of the body is there but I also see the mime boundary and content type rather than the email being HTML

```
    --==Multipart_Boundary_x9e92752e972e274a182cc4cafd83c674xContent-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>
    Body content</p>
<p> <snip>
```

The code looks like this:

```
 $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

   $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $message = "--{$mime_boundary}Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" . $bodyText . "\r\n";   

      $message .=  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
   $message . "\n\n";

then the attachment routine
```

I've tried many variations on the code without success.  No doubt it will be something trivial I just can't see.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the correct line endings twice.

```
   $message = "--{$mime_boundary}Content-Type"
```

There is the first `\r\n` missing.

```
 $message .=  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
```

Here you only wrote `\n` instead of `\r\n`.

Also don't forget that you need a terminating MIME boundary at the very end with a closing double minus as terminator:

```
  $message .=  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n" .
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the required CRLF after the boundary delimiter, and also possibly that the delimiter may be indented (which it must not be), though that might just be the code formatting here.  It also looks like you're using only newlines instead of the mandatory CRLFs.

You should seriously consider using [a mature mailing library, like SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to assemble MIME messages for you with ease.

Comment: +1 for SwiftMailer... or PHPMailer will do... just anything other than the raw `mail` function.

Comment: I have used phpmailer in the past but sometimes it feels like overkill.  Will keep that in mind though.

Comment: yes. +1 for that. I found article [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php) which would be useful.

Comment: PHPMailer and SwiftMailer can both be a bit overkill, but having their power ready to wield at a moment's notice has been *incredibly* convenient.